'how far from~' sentence in grammar

How far 'is it' from here to the nearest gas station?

How far from here to the nearest gas station?


Does both sentences grammarly correct?
Like 2) sentence, Can I omit the 'is it'?

Are both sentences grammatically correct?  Your second sentence would be understood, but I would find it more natural to say "How far [from here] is the nearest gas station?"

Both are idiomatic in American English.  The second is a little hurried and of the two, it is more likely to be used when the distance is a critical fact, for example, when you have very little gas left in the tank.

There are several other variants possible. For example "How far is it to the nearest gas station" , "How far are we from the ..." or even "How close is the ..."

In formal English, a verb is expected in each sentence. The shortest sentence is, 'Go!" just a verb (subject "you" is understood). Following that rule, the second example is not a sentence. Nevertheless, in informal, colloquial speech, it's often heard, and understood (though some people might find it offensive, to be cut short, so).

Yes, both sentences are grammatically correct, but they have a slightly different tone and formality.
"How far is it from here to the nearest gas station?" - This is the more traditional and formal way to ask the question. It's completely grammatical and clear.
"How far from here to the nearest gas station?" - This is less formal and sounds more like casual speech. It's still understandable but drops the verb "is" and the pronoun "it," which is common in casual or quick speech.
Here's another example for clarity:
Formal: "How long will it take to get to the airport?"
Casual: "How long to the airport?"
Both ways work; the second is just a bit more casual.

Some pedants would complain about "How far from here to the nearest gas station?" because it doesn't have a verb and hence isn't a sentence. But lots of things people say aren't complete sentences, so it's fine casually.

This is accurate. People sometimes just use intonation to signal a question. +1
